# output several values from different arrays consecutively

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays:

```
print_r($_SESSION['cart']); echo '<br>';
print_r($_SESSION['itemamount']); echo '<br>';
print_r($_SESSION['itemproduct'])
```

with values respectively:

```
Array ( [sugar] => 989.32 [lolli] => 77 [isi] => 0.99 ) 
Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 11 [2] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 12861.16 [1] => 847 [2] => 1.98 )
```

I am trying to do a `foreach` loop for all their values at the same time and all I could think of was:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2) 
foreach($_SESSION['itemamount'] as $amount1=>$amount2)
foreach($_SESSION['itemproduct'] as $product1=>$product2)
{echo $data1 . '   x' . $amount2,
'<ul> price:', $product2 . '<br></ul>';}
```

it worked but it replicated the output 9 times. Help please.

```
sugar x2
price:1978.64
sugar x2
price:847
sugar x2
price:1.98
sugar x11
price:1978.64
sugar x11
price:847
sugar x11
price:1.98
sugar x2
price:1978.64
sugar x2
price:847
sugar x2
price:1.98
lolli x2
price:1978.64
lolli x2
price:847
lolli x2
price:1.98
lolli x11
price:1978.64
lolli x11
price:847
lolli x11
price:1.98
lolli x2
price:1978.64
lolli x2
price:847
lolli x2
price:1.98
isi x2
price:1978.64
isi x2
price:847
isi x2
price:1.98
isi x11
price:1978.64
isi x11
price:847
isi x11
price:1.98
isi x2
price:1978.64
isi x2
price:847
isi x2
price:1.98
```

Comment: Does your arrays always have the same number of keys?

Comment: yeah. The last two where somewhat derived from the $_SESSION['name'].

Comment: Could you please specify your expected output? There are a lot of different combinations.

Comment: my expected output is to be one each of the 4 instances and not 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all arrays have the same size, use [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator):

```
$i = new MultipleIterator;
$i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($cart));
$i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($amount));
$i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($product));

foreach ($i as $value) {
    $keys = $i->key();
    echo $keys[0]; // 'sugar'
    echo $keys[1]; // 0
    echo $keys[2]; // 0

    echo $value[0]; // 989.32
    echo $value[1]; // 13
    echo $value[2]; // 12861.16
}
```

Only the results of the first iteration are given in the comments.

Comment: ...so it takes all arrays and appends them to one array and calls out values when cycling through the keys, am i correct?

Comment: @brown.cn No, it iterates each array at the same type with each cycle.

Comment: wow. it works...but i'd really appreciate it if you had a simpler, less complex version. Thanks still. Will try to wrap my head around it

Comment: @brown.cn There would be a simpler way if you didn't have mixed associative and numeric arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following should give you the desired result.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data1 => $data2){
   echo "{$data1} x {$_SESSION['itemamount'][$counter]}";
   echo "<ul>price: {$_SESSION['itemproduct'][$counter]}</ul>";
   $counter++;
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: `$counter = 0;` should be out of the `foreach`